# Is this a valid quicksort implementation?

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

Is this a valid implementation of quicksort? It is different from how I have seen it implemented elsewhere, but I find it easier personally to implement it this way. As far as I can tell, it is still in-place and O(n log n) [edit: O(n log n) expected run time, O(n^2) worst-case], but want to make sure before I do it in a job interview and look like an idiot...

```
//Quicksort of arr between low and high
public static void myqs(int[] arr, int low, int high){
    if(arr == null){
        return;
    }

    if(low >= high){
        return;
    }

    //get pivot value, put it at the end of the chunk
    int pivotIndex = low + ((high - low) / 2);
    int pivot = arr[pivotIndex];
    swap(arr,pivotIndex,high);

    //move any lower number to the low end of chunk
    int lowIndex = low;
    for(int i = low; i < high; i++){
        if(arr[i] < pivot){
            swap(arr,lowIndex,i);
            lowIndex++;
        }
    }
    //move pivot value between low/high chunks
    swap(arr, lowIndex, high);

    //recurse on lower/upper halves
    myqs(arr, low, lowIndex - 1);
    myqs(arr, lowIndex + 1, high);
}

//swap values at indices i and j in arr
public static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j){
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Maybe try testing it...?

Comment: It's certainly in-place (as there are no arrays allocated); but why do you think it is `O(n log n)`? (quicksort is `O(n^2)` in the worst case)

Comment: Yes, I have tested it and it works fine in testing. I am more concerned with whether I am misunderstanding the runtime. Also, yes I suppose I should have said O(n^2) worst case, O(n log n) expected.

Comment: The example code is a variation of Lomuto partition scheme. [Hoare partition scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Hoare_partition_scheme) is more efficient. One test is to generate all permutations of numbers 1 through n for n = 8 to 12. Do a web search for "next permutation" to see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks good (but you should try it to be sure), but it is not in `O(n log(n))`.

Indeed, it is possible to send a particular array that will trigger `n` recursive calls, by always having the greatest value as the middle, which gives a total complexity of `N^2`.

For instance: `1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 5, 6`. `7` will be the pivot, so the array will be divided into an empty array and `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.
In that case, only the first split is “bad”, but you can easily imagine how one can make all splits bad.

To get an `O(N log(N))` **average** complexity, the most popular solution is to chose the pivot randomly.

Comment: Choosing the pivot randomly also has a worst case of N^2, and choosing the pivot to be the middle element has an average complexity of N log N.  The typical solution is to choose the pivot to be the median of a fixed number of elements from the array, which still has the same average and worst case performance, but makes the worst case much less likely.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You are right, of course, in that it is O(n^2) worst-case. I had forgotten that the pivot quality can have a significant effect.